# cpp LinkedList and Node. Should data be a pointer or a reference?

Tags: c++

This is for a homework assignment in a cpp course and I'm looking for some best practises.

I've got a rather complex class that I would like to store in a linkedlist class. I must implement my own, including a node class. I need to only store this single relatively complex type I'm working on.

Should I make the node's data type a reference to the complex type, or should I make it a pointer to it instead?

Option 1:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    ComplexType *data;
}
```

Option 2:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    ComplexType &data;
}
```

Assuming I will also need to handle the different cases of copying value when working with the reference solution. Which one is considered more correct? And why?

Comment: Any reason not to store a `ComplexType` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a reference is initialised, it cannot be changed again to reference anything else. Therefore your list will be more useful/flexible if you stick with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for option 2. Your prev and next need to be pointers, since they can change. A nodes data shouldn't change in a list. Only its position in the list should change by altering the prev/next pointers. In my opinion its always the best if you can prevent using pointers where possible, but in this case your prev/next member should be pointers, since they can change.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need the freedom to have null `data`, as well as changing it after construction. In this case, you would need pointers of some variety.